# Circular law from the semi-circle law

Tags: soft-question, fake-proofs, random-matrices

Here is a faulty proof of the [circular law of random matrix theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law):

> Take a random matrix $M$ with i.i.d. complex entries and write it as $A+iB$,
> where $A:=(M+M^*)/2$ and $iB:=(M-M^*)/2$ are the Hermitian and
> skew-Hermitian parts of $M$, respectively. By the [Wigner semicircle law](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WignersSemicircleLaw.html),
> a randomly picked eigenvalue of $A$ or $B$ obeys the Wigner
> semicircle distribution, that is, the distribution of the first
> component of a random point on the disk. Hence, a randomly picked
> eigenvalue of $A+iB$ is uniformly distributed in the disk.

Obviously the problem with this proof is that eigenvalues are not additive -- the $k$th eigenvalue of $M$ is not the $k$th eigenvalue of $A$ plus the $k$th eigenvalue of $iB$.

Nevertheless, is there any moral truth to the proof above, maybe because the randomness makes eigenvalues almost additive in the required sense?